# fetch value to the drop down list

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

Just want to know that how to fetch a value to the drop-down list. The drop-down list has all the values from database. The value that I'm fetching to the drop-down list is from table, which I'm going to update.

This is the 'display table page' :

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
     echo " <tr>
        <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' width='145px' align='center'>".$row['patientid']."</td>
        <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' width='145px' align='center'>".$row['trandate']."</td>
        <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' width='600px'>".$row['trandescription']."</td>
        <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' width='90px' align='center'>".$row['tranquantity']."</td>
        <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' width='90px' align='right'>".number_format($row['tranunitprice'],2)."</td>
        <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray' width='150px' align='right'>".number_format($row['tranamount'],2)."</td>
       <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray'><a href='updatebillindex.php?update=$row[id]'>update</a></td>
       <td style='border:1px solid; color:gray'><button class='btn btn-default btn-sm';><a href='updatebillindex.php?update=$row[0]'>edit
       <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a></button></td>
      </tr> "; }
```

this is the **'update page with dropdown list from the database'**

```
     <select name="selectmedicine" class="form-control col-sm-4" id="medicinename">
     <option id="0" style="width:100px"></option>
     <option id="anti-rabbies" value="30001">anti-rabbies</option><option id="medicol" value="30002">medicol</option><option id="medicol-white" value="30003">medicol-white</option>                                                                                            
     </select>

   <?php
        if (isset($_GET['update'])) 
        {

        $id = $_GET['update'];

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transaction where id = '$id'") or die ("could not search");
        $count = mysql_num_rows($query);    

        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

        $id = $rows['id'];
        $tranid = $rows['tranid'];
        $trandate = $rows['trandate'];
        $patientid = $rows['patientid'];
        $transactiontype = $rows['transactiontype'];
        $trandescription = $rows['trandescription'];
        $tranquantity = $rows['tranquantity'];
        $tranunitprice = $rows['tranunitprice'];
        $tranamount =$rows['tranamount'];
        $gettrandescription = $rows['trandescription'];

        }

}

        ?>

        <form action="billindex.php" method="POST">

        <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo "$id"; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="tranid" value="<?php echo "$tranid"; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="patientid" value="<?php echo "$patientid"; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="trandate" value="<?php echo "$trandate"; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="transactiontype" value="<?php echo "$transactiontype"; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="trandescription" value="<?php echo "$trandescription"; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="tranquanity" value="<?php echo "$tranquantity"; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="tranunitprice" value="<?php echo "$tranunitprice"; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="tranamount" value="<?php echo "$tranamount"; ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">

        </form>

        <?php
        echo "$trandescription";
        ?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to say that you need to show dropdown values from the database instead of writing it static ?
OR you mean to say that you need to show selected value in the list.

Comment: i need to show the selected value to dropdown list from table display which i need to update.

Comment: sorry for the late reply

Comment: what do you mean by "from table display which i need to update" ?
Sorry, it is not clear at all.

Comment: Do ypu mean this : You need to show a selected value in drop-down that comes from database and then you need to save that value in your database in a new table ?

Comment: no sir, i have table displayed on webpage with an update link on each row.  the value from the displayed table is am going to display on dropdown list, is which this dropdown is already on the next page/updatepage.

Comment: i aready updated the code above. the variable $transdecription and $tranquantity are the value am going to display on dropdown which has same value on the list.

Comment: btw, variable $tranquantity, has a separate dropdown list not shown above  but same as select medicine dropdown list above.

Answer (score 0):

either `$_POST['selectmedicine]` or `$_GET['selectmedicine']` depending on your form action

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tr><td>valueDisplayed</td>
<td><a href="updatePage.php?val=valueDisplayed">Update</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**updatePage.php**

```
$addToDropdown = $_GET['val'];
```

You can add the value in $addToDropdown to your dropdown

Comment: After seeing your code, what I understand is that you want the dropdown value to be sent to billindex.php along with the other values so that you can update it in your database. If this is so, just make the dropdown a part of the form i.e. put the `<select>...</select>` block in the `<form> element`. As there is no dropdown in the table given in piece of code 1.

Comment: no, i already have a dropdown and has a value from database. the select option above is the actual dropdown list i have from database. I want to display the value am going to update into the dropdown so i can change the value.

Comment: the dropdown is where the update will took place, thats  why i have to display the value to dropdown as selected value.